# Convert numeric data such as "715" into Date "July-2015" in R

Tags: r, date, numeric

I would like to friendly ask a question about converting numeric data into Date format.

I would like to convert the numeric data like:

```
time1<-c(715, 1212, 0416)
```

to

```
July-2015, Dec-2012, Apr-2016
```

I have tried these code but it is not working.

```
time2<-as.Date(as.character(time1), format="%m%y")
```

Does anyone have some ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: What language?  C#? Java? Prolog?

Comment: do you mean  TimeStamp

Comment: It is `R` language. Sorry I forget to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the issue is that "July 2015", "December 2012", and "April 2016" are not dates since the specific day is missing. Another approach is to convert to `zoo::yearmon`. Here, the numeric input needs to be converted to a string with leading zero so that the month is from `01` to `12`:

```
library(zoo)
ym <- as.yearmon(sprintf("%04d",time1),format="%m%y")
ym
##[1] "Jul 2015" "Dec 2012" "Apr 2016"
```

The result is of class `yearmon`, which can then be coerced to `Date`:

```
class(ym)
##[1] "yearmon"
d <- as.Date(ym)
d
##[1] "2015-07-01" "2012-12-01" "2016-04-01"
class(d)
##[1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `lubridate::parse_date_time()`:

```
library(lubridate)
time2 <- parse_date_time(time1, orders = "my")
format.Date(time2, "%b-%Y")
[1] "juil.-2015" "déc.-2012"  "avril-2016" # my locale lang is French
```

Comment: Thank you so much @scoa. The interesting thing is this code convert "715" to "Jun-2015". I assume the month is from 0 to 11? I think this solution is close but is there any way to convert the month from 1 to 12?

Comment: Looks like the code converts '715' to 'Jul-2015', as intended.